# How to perform a multipart upload using AWS CLI s3api command?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

From my understanding, an S3 object-store should be able to resume incomplete multipart uploads. I am trying to test this against a local S3 storage system.

I'm aware the AWS CLI will automatically perform a multipart upload on larger files via `aws s3 cp`, but how do I perform the same operation using `aws s3api`?

I've read the documentation and know that it's a three step process:

1. Run `aws s3api create-multipart-upload` ([docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/create-multipart-upload.html))
2. Run `aws s3api upload-part` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/upload-part.html))
3. Finish by running `aws s3api complete-multipart-upload` which reconstructs the object ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/complete-multipart-upload.html))

I attempted to perform these steps against a file that was 7GB in size. After running the first command, I received the expected `upload-id` which is required for all subsequent commands:

```
aws --profile foo --endpoint-url=https://endpoint:9003 s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket mybucket1 --key 'some7gfile.bin/01' --output json
{
    "Bucket": "mybucket1", 
    "UploadId": "41a1462d-0d23-47f6-83aa-377e7aedbb8a", 
    "Key": "some7gfile.bin/01"
}
```

I assumed the `01` portion of `some7gfile.bin/01` denoted the first part, but that doesn't appear to be the case. What does the `01` mean? Is it arbitrary?

When I tried running the second `upload-part` command, I received an error:

```
aws --profile foo --endpoint-url=https://endpoint:9003 s3api upload-part --bucket mybucket1 --key 'some7gfile.bin/01' --part-number 1 --body part01 --upload-id "41a1462d-0d23-47f6-83aa-377e7aedbb8a" --output json

Error parsing parameter '--body': Blob values must be a path to a file.
```

Does the source file have to be split into different parts prior to running the `upload-part` step? If so, what's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're specifying the key as `--key 'some7gfile.bin/01'` in your command so that is what is being confirmed to you? And are you doing this for educational purposes? Do you have to use the lower level API? Matter of just knowing how to?

Comment: And yes, `upload-part` expects a part of the final object, if you're attempting to upload one file, you will need to split it to upload each part, the Unix command `split` will work for this, as will others.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I used that value for key based on the provided example in the create-multipart-upload doc’s page, which is `aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket my-bucket --key 'multipart/01'`. The definition for key doesn’t clarify much: > “ Object key for which the multipart upload is to be initiated.”